# Add to list within document MongoDB

Tags: list, mongodb, collections, document

I have a database where I store player names that belong to people who have certain items.
The items have and IDs, and subIDs.
The way I am currently storing everything is:

Each ID has its own collection

Within the collection there is a document for each subID.
The document for each subID is layed out like so:

{
"itemID":itemID,
"playerNames":[playerName1, playerName2, playerName3]
}

I need to be able to add to the list of playerNames quickly and efficiently.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you need to add items to the "playerNames" array. You can use one of the following operators:

1. If the player names array will have unique elements in it, use [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)
2. Otherwise, use [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)